# setting capabilities in ruby for selenium webdriver for proxy error "access denied"

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Example of setting capabilities in ruby for IE driver proxy error "access denied" for selenium webdriver.

I have tried security level "internet". I hav been using "HTTP_PROXY" environment variable which is mandatory in my oraganization.

Answer (score 0):

For selenium-webdriver > 2.25.0,  `NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1` setting may help you to run it in your local env. Read [this documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) for using a proxy in Internet Explorer, if it does't solve your problem paste you error log.

Comment: Solved it using ENV[HTTP_PROXY] = nil in env.rb file